How did the money go from buyers to the firm's account?
There's a scenario in the The Wolf of Wall Street movie where it talks about the trades executed in pink market, and the OTC counter charges 50% of total value as commissions.
Now I'm wondering these,

When you buy stock shares from a secondary market, how does the money go to the firm's account? I want to know the whole process.
For an established stock exchange like NYSE or NASDAQ, how much money would they receive?
Can I find these information in the financial statements, which part should I look into?


If "the firm" in question 1 and "they" in question 2 refer to the company whose stock you are buying, no money goes to the company when shares are traded.

Are you asking how settlements of stock exchange transactions work?

@littleadv Yes, that's part of it. Another part is how does the company raise money by listing on the exchange.

@daisy well that other part is simple - by selling pieces of itself (shares of ownership).

@littleadv But not according to Justin's comment. Do company actually get the money in the secondary market or only during the IPO process?

@daisy During IPO and only that. Once a share is sold, it is sold.

@glglgl Companies can issue new shares after the IPO.  This is normal and common.

@JimmyJames Right, but that is primary market as well. On the secondary market, the company doesn't get any money (except if it sells some on its own, but I am not sure whether that's possible).

@glglgl Definitely possible: https://www.globenewswire.com/en/news-release/2024/06/11/2897180/0/en/GameStop-Completes-At-The-Market-Equity-Offering-Program.html

JimmyJames and @glglgl you both seem to be confusing the concepts of "secondary market" and "at the market offering". While at the same market, primary and secondary refers to the sellers. Primary is the company, secondary is another shareholder. Subsequent offerings (at the market or otherwise) are still going through a different process than just dumping a bunch of "sell" orders.

Highly related: https://money.stackexchange.com/q/94507/7513


When you buy stock shares from a secondary market, how does the money goto the firm's account? I want to know the whole process.

It doesn't. That's what "secondary" means. You're buying from another shareholder, so the money goes to them, not to the company. It's akin to buying a used car - the money doesn't go to the car manufacturer.
The companies raise money by selling shares of themselves through initial or subsequent public offering (both colloquially referred to as IPO, even though I stands for "initial", the first kind), that would be the "primary" market. Once sold the companies have no involvement any more and the new shareholders can continue trading their shares on the secondary market.

For an established stock exchange like NYSE or NASDAQ, how much money would they receive?

For primary market transactions? Depends on the situation. There are fees and costs accompanying IPOs like underwriting, accounting, legal, fees to the stock exchanges, associated costs for marketing and shareholder management, etc.

Can I find these information in the financial statements, which part should I look into?

Usually in the IPO prospectus.

This has nothing to do with the situation you're describing from the movie. There, the OTC transaction (still secondary market) includes a hefty fee to the broker (the Wolf). The actual Wolf of Wall Street committed several crimes, including pump and dump schemes, the absurd fees were the least of the problems.

Just one clarification: the initial public offering (IPO) only refers to the initial issuance on public markets.  Companies can and do issue new shares after that but that's not called an IPO.

Yes, they're called "subsequent" public offering, as mentioned in the answer

"or subsequent public offering (aka IPO)" is confusing, IMO.

I've seen both types of offerings being colloquially referred to as "IPO", laymen probably won't be able to differentiate.

There seems to be a common misconception that after the IPO, a company can never sell more shares (see question comments) which is 100% incorrect.  Typically these are referred to as "new share offerings", in my experience.  The IPO is only when the company first becomes public.

"laymen probably won't be able to differentiate" most laymen won't be aware of the subsequent offerings since they rarely make news. I think the point of this forum should be to help illuminate and educate people on such matters, not confirm incorrect notions.  Sometimes I get the sense other lurkers don't agree with that, but I don't understand why.

Just to be curious, If an IPO is undersubscribed, what happens to those unsold shares? Do they make subsequent offering or just keep the shares themselves?

Either can happen, whatever the company needs

As far as investors are concerned, there's little significant difference between an IPO and a subsequent offering -- in both cases what you pay largely goes to the company, rather than other shareholders. IPO is more important to the company itself because it marks the transition from a private to a public company.

@Barmar There is a significant difference between initial and subsequent offerings. At the IPO, no market price has yet been established for the stock, so the offer price is a guess skewed low to avoid the offer failing. You’re thus much more likely to make a large day-one profit if investing in an IPO than in a subsequent offering.

Regarding the first point, you're assuming that "the firm" means the company associated with the stock being traded.  But in context of "The Wolf of Wall Street", OP's question makes a whole lot more sense if you interpret that as "brokerage firm".  (Even though daisy doesn't seem to have known that)

@BenVoigt That's what I thought at first, too. But then the answer seems too obvious --  you simply send a check to your brokerage. It would be like asking how the money gets to the supermarket when you buy groceries.
