# How do companies profit after initial shares have been sold?

Tags: investing, trading, limited-liability-company, selling, profitability

I have experience in investing and invest in several mutual funds each month, I understand the concepts of how the *investor* makes money from shares (either by dividend pay-outs or increases in share price). I also understand how a *company* initially makes money from selling shares, they... well, sell shares!

What I don't understand is how they ***continue*** to make money (from the market) once the initial shares have been sold.

Here is an example:

- Company A goes public and creates 100 shares, the Owner keeps 50 shares and lists the other 50 on the stock market for $5 each
- 50 shares are sold at $5 each, the company now has $250 to use for buying equipment
- 1 year later, the share price has doubled, so the initial investors have made money and the 50 shares traded publicly are now worth $500 combined
- Now the owner wants to raise more money through the market... ***how?*** Can they 'split' one of their shares into more shares and sell them at the new value? Isn't that just creating artificial money out of nothing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would a company care about the price of its own shares in the stock market?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7800/why-would-a-company-care-about-the-price-of-its-own-shares-in-the-stock-market)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now the owner wants to raise more money through the market... how? Can they 'split' one of their shares into more shares and sell them at the new value? Isn't that just creating artificial money out of nothing?

They can indeed issue more shares from nothing.

**But note.**

The initial shares in your point two are shares issued from nothing.

That's what stock is!

If the sense of your question is **"wow, that is open to being a big scam!"** that is **absolutely correct**. Indeed, **that is the very reason** public companies / shares / the markets are so **highly regulated** in our era. Your question is astute.

A fun thing to do is read up on the **history of stock, basically in England, so that's from about 1700**.  Exactly as your question hints, there were endless huge, often rather ridiculous, scams and cons.  Well, not really "scams", I mean, if the public is stupid enough to buy "nothing" en masse, that's life - but you will see exactly what an unregulated stock market was like!

Comment: Thanks Fattie. Do you have any book recommendations about this? Sounds interesting!

Comment: yeah good question @Cloud .. what about *Devil take the hindmost*  .. really any good book on 1700s Britain ... we Brits slaughtered everyone in the new world, invented markets as we know them, did a bit of pirating, founded various minor institutions such as "the USA" .. it was a lot of hurly burly.  I always truly recommend the great book Free Banking in Britain Book (L White) which is about non-government monies and relates to it.  And what about "Against the Gods" - awesome

Comment: @Fattie: Slaughtered everyone?  Hardly.  Even leaving out South America, and North America south of the Rio Grande, there are still lots of us here.  And many of us have some ancestors who were here quite a while before you Brits showed up.

Comment: @jamesqf The Piper Tomahawk *was* a widely manufactured aircraft

Comment: @Cloud: I'm well aware of that, though I chose a Cherokee myself.  But what does that have to do with the question?  There is an aviation StackExchange site, you know.

Answer (score 5):

> What I don't understand is how they ***continue*** to make money (from the market) once the initial shares have been sold.

As you intuit, they don't, because, of course, the purpose of business is to make money through *sales*; an IPO is seed capital for growth.

> Now the owner wants to raise more money through the market... ***how?***

Issue more shares.  A *Secondary* Public Offering, if you will.

Of course, that will dilute existing shareholder value, so first must be approved by existing shareholders.

Another method, is for this "SPO" to be *pre-approved*, and the company having unissued shares "in their back pockets" ready to be issued *when they need more money*, **not** just when the stock price is high.

> Can they 'split' one of their shares into more shares and sell them at the new value?

That's a stock split.  It doesn't happen on *one* share; it happens on **all** shares.

> Isn't that just creating artificial money out of nothing?

It's a neutral action, because the price of each share changes *inversely* with the number of shares.

For example: in a 2:1 split, the total number of shares *doubles* from 1 million to 2 million while the price *halves* from $100/share to $50/share.

Thus, before and after the market capitalization is the same.

Comment: The last bit isn’t true. If a company with 1 million issued shares and a market cap of $100 million issues 1 million new shares _and sells them_ then (ignoring consultancy, underwriting and dealing costs) its market cap should now be $200 million, because it has an extra $100 million in the bank that it didn’t have before, and the share price stays the same at $100. The extra money isn’t created out of nowhere, it comes from the new shareholders.

Comment: @MikeScott you're talking about a "Secondary Public Offering", not a stock split.

Comment: @MikeScott - A stock split does not change the value of the shares, the value of a company, or the value of a shareholder's position.  What you are referring to is a "Secondary Public Offering".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, quick secondary question - is there a limit to how many shares can be issued per company?

Comment: @Cloud technically, no.  Practically, yes: #1 a quadrillion shares would be a bit unwieldy; #2 investors, might not want to buy more shares of a company; #3 current owners might not want to dilute their ownership.

Comment: @Cloud Every company that issues stock has some maximum number of shares they are currently authorized to issue. That often is far fewer than the number actually issued. It usually takes a stockholder vote to increase that limit.